# Execute operations in script IFF specified file has been modified within 7 days

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

What I am trying to do is to copy a file named myFile from directory A to directory B. After this I perform some operations on the file I have just copied to directory B. This works fine. However I want the script to run all operations IFF the file in directory A has been modified within the past 7 days. Else it should do nothing. So basically I want:

```
#!/bin/sh

if ((modification date of myFile in dir A) >= (current date minus 7 days))

    DO STUFF

else

    DO NOTHING

end
```

So the operations to be performed are already up and running. I only need the conditional structure described in the above pseudo-code. Does somebody know how to construct that for a bash script?

Comment: Take a look at the `find` utility, it offers search operations for `ctime` and the like.

Comment: `find` is overkill if you only want the modification time of a single file. Use `stat` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the test by writing:

```
filepath="your/file/path"
if [[ $(find ${filepath} -mtime -7 | wc -l) ]]; then
    # modified within past 7 days
else
    # not modified within the last 7 days
fi
```

From `man find`:

```
-mtime n
       File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the  comments
       for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation
       of file modification times.

Numeric arguments can be specified as

+n     for greater than n,

-n     for less than n,

 n     for exactly n.
```